# GUI - the old style (Java)

Tags: java, user-interface, dos

I'm desperate: I've been looking for quite a long time now on how to create "old-fashioned Graphical User Interfaces" in Java (like VIM). Well, but VIM is not written in Java (unfortunately). I'm sure it's possible, but I really don't know how.
If you still don't know what I'm intending to do, here's a screenshot of VIM http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Vim-(logiciel)-console.png

Comment: That looks more like a shell than a GUI.

Comment: You may be able to replicate with something like this: http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/

Comment: Check out escape codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to mimic the same look and feel and behavior with java / swing. You dont use buttons, but you are responding to commands that are entered, there are global event listeners in swing, that can help achieve this too.

Comment: I think that app needs to run in a non-graphics-capable terminal window.

Comment: @user1598390 Thank You, did'nt understand that from the op question.